# Get network information with WMI

Tags: c#, asp.net, wmi

I have to create a resource monitoring dashboard (like Task Manager) in my web project. I'm using WMI. I could get `CurrentBandwidth` and `BytesTotalPersec` from `Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface` but it returns 7 items (Task Manager shows just 4 items in the Network tab). I found that some of the items are disabled; I can find which ones are enabled using `NetEnabled` in `Win32_NetworkAdapter`, but how can I join these two? How can I show network information just like Task Manager?

I want to get network information like Task Manager shows (e.g. `AdapterName`, `Utilization` (for this I have to get bandwidth and total send/receive bytes/sec), `Speed`, and state). I can get some of this by using `Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface` and others by using `Win32_NetworkAdapter`. For example, I can get all networks' send/receive bytes/sec with `BytesTotalPersec` member of  'Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface', but this retrieves all networks' (including disabled)  data. How can I get the send/receive bytes/sec measurement for only enabled networks?

Comment: Please clarify your request. What are you trying to join? What are you unable to access?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use WQL Queries.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392902(v=vs.85).aspx

So your first query will be something like this

```
"SELECT Name FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetEnabled = 'true'"
```

After you have that list, you can do a for-each on that IEnumerable and call a query like like on each one:

```
"SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface WHERE Name = '" + adapter + "'"
```

But, you might find some interesting problems like the fact that the names don't always match exactly. On my machine, the NetworkAdapterWMI prefixes the name with "Intel(R)" and the NetworkInterfacesWMI prefixes the same name with "Intel[R]" so you might need to do a little transformation between the two queries.

Hopefully this will get you start in the right direction.

Comment: It's just my problem, I couldn't find unique property in common between these two classes. in additional retrieved items from these two class are not equivalent. Win32_NetworkAdapter return 19 items and Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface return 7 items.

Comment: From my experience, not all of the WMI providers are equally helpful and consistent. Typically, they have what you need, but often you have to look at other WMI classes or dig into the fields.  The documentation helps with that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx